# Ebean / Play Framework 2.1 issues fetching a parent/children tree structure

Tags: orm, playframework, playframework-2.1, ebean

I encountered a problem when trying to fetch a tree structure (parent/children elements in one table).

Using the class below, starting with the root node, I can use getSubNodes() and will receive its children. However, if I then call getSubNodes() on a child node which has itself child nodes in the db, getSubNodes() will return an empty list (the db data contains multiple tree levels)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "navigation_items")
public class NavigationItem extends Model {

    public static NavigationItemFinder find = new NavigationItemFinder();
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @Column (unique=true)
    private String key;

    @ManyToOne
    private NavigationItem parentNode;

    @OneToMany (mappedBy="parentNode", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<NavigationItem> subNodes;

    @Column
    @Required
    private String title;

    @Column
    private String subtitle;

    @ManyToOne
    private PageBlock page;
```

...

```
    public List<NavigationItem> getSubNodes() {
        return subNodes; // <- This crazily but provenly only returns results on the first level of the hierarchy...

    }
```

If I however do not return the subnodes property using the getter, but instead use a finder query, all works as expected and the full tree can be retrieved:

```
    List<NavigationItem> result = find.where().eq("parentNode", this).findList();       
    Logger.debug("NavItem " + getTitle() + "[" + getId() +"]" + ": returning # subnodes: " + result.size());
```

Am I missing something here, or could this be an(other) ebean bug?

Comment: bachi, have you found a solution for this issue?

Comment: @tavlima, nope, we've run into other issues and then decided to switch to JPA, which solved most things.

Answer (score 0):

try this
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "currentTablecolumnName", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)